# Spool CSV format different on IDE vs Batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am trying to use a batch file to run a sql script which outputs a csv into a folder destination. When i run script (F5) on my Oracle SQL Developer, it outputs the csv as expected. But when i run it on the batch file, the output comes out with dashes and column comes out row by row, like this:
[batchoutputcsv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bPTy.png)

Is there a reason why my Spool output on IDE is different from my batch script?

Thank you for your time and help.

Kind Regards,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

After testing I've found out spool for batch outputs whatever you see on the cmd window. After applying the correct spool formatting settings such as truncating long values, the outputs are looking as intended.